# Bootstrap fixed navbar navbar-brand add to logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hello i'm using Bootsrap fixed navbar. When i put to place of PROJECT NAME some logo header behave different. When resize to the browser i get some conflicts.. mobil menu open automaticly why?

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="last"><a href="../navbar/"><img src="assets/img/home.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Rates</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Remote</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I mean here.

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"/></a>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. Can you replicate in a fiddle? Here's one set up with Bootstrap 3: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RLrBE/

Comment: Yes It's bootsrap 2 http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RLrBE/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/czengin/A4KPJ/

Comment: That fiddle is empty.

Comment: i don't understand why. this is share link. So i didn't change anything on css i take from here this template http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/  and put there only logo

Comment: Did you click Update before copying the URL?

Comment: Yep now is okey : http://jsfiddle.net/czengin/A4KPJ/1/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap's JavaScript. I provided a fiddle that does. I've put your HTML into my fiddle and it seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RLrBE/2

Comment: http://ifelselab.com/ak.jpg check this image please this is problem what i speak about.

Comment: when resize to browser menu going under the logo before open mobile navigation

Answer (score 0):

You simply have too much stuff for the available width at certain screen sizes. Try this (reduce space between menu items for that screen width range):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/RLrBE/4

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .nav > li > a {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: i put your code. but was same. then i change padding:10px with padding:4px and solved.